# Can't find basic Python syntax error (Tkinter)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm using python 2.7 and the code below:

```
def showScore(score):

    score = 1.5

    scoreKeeper = tk.Label(window, text=score)

    if (score >= 2.0)
    scoreKeeper.configure(text = "Too loud. Try again.") 

    scoreKeeper.pack()
```

I am getting the error

```
  File "tkinter_oqy01.py", line 18
    if (score >= 2.0)
                    ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and obviously can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `:` in your if statement

Your if statement should be

```
if (score >= 2.0):

    scoreKeeper.configure(text = "Too loud. Try again.")
```

You're also checking if the score will be greater than two, but score will always be 1.5 since your setting score = 1.5 despite the score passed to the function.

score also isn't a string. So if you tried to run your program even after fixing that you'd get another error. you should be setting `text = str(score)`

Comment: Oh duh. Missing a comma. Thank you, would have continued going crazy. I am changing the values of score manually for now to test the code. Thanks!